# Update href and download file on button click

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am trying to download a file on clicking a button. My exact approach is as follows:

1. On the button click I call an API which returns the files Buffer Data
2. Convert buffer data to a base64 url and update the href of the `<a>` element with this base64 url
3. invoke a click to the `<a>` element from inside the function

This approach will download the file, however, it keeps downloading the file infinitely and I'm not sure why its doing that and how to get around it.

Here is how I'm calling the function

```
<button v-on:click="this.getImage([imageID, imageName], $event)"><a>View scoresheet</a></button>
```

Here is the function:

```
getImage: async function(info, event){
    fetch('endpoint' + String(info[0]) + "/" + String(info[1]) , {
        method: 'GET',
      
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(async result => {
             var image_data = await result.image_buffer.data
             var imgSrc = "data:image/jpg;base64," + btoa(
                 image_data.reduce((data, byte) => data + String.fromCharCode(byte), '')
             );

             event.target.href = imgSrc
             event.target.download = 'image.jpg'
             event.target.click()
        })
    },
```

Comment: *it keeps downloading the file infinitely* <-- What does that mean? Have you checked to ensure that the download contents are correct?

Comment: The `event.target.click()` keeps getting invoked and I keep downloading copies of the file. I have checked the contents of the file and they are correct

Comment: Consider using `event.preventDefault()`. Could be a timing issue between Vue's event handling and the native handler

Comment: Simple: you are reusing the same `a` element, instead of creating a new one. This, every scripted `click` event at the end of `getImage()` triggers the click listener, and `getImage()` is called again.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes that was it! Creating a new `a` element on a the button click is downloading the file only once. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are reusing the same `a` element. Thus, the `click` event triggered at the end of `getImage()` triggers the click listener, and `getImage()` is called again, creating an infinite loop of `getImage()` calls.

To fix it, create a new `a` element in `getImage()` and use that as your script's "download" `a`.

For example:

```js
const el = document.createElement('a')

el.href = imgSrc
el.download = 'image.jpg'
el.click()
```